# Each html file include it's own js script

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a webpack config js like this:

```
entry: {
    language: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts/lang.js'),
    config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts/config.js'),
    mainFunctions: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts/utilFunctions.js'),
},
```

And this script sequence bottom of html file:

```
<script src="../plugins/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/Popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/Magnific/magnificPopup.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

So after compile `HtmlWebpackPlugin` generates a this structure:

```
<script src="../plugins/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/Popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/Magnific/magnificPopup.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src=".././js/language-82d9013312d51ba09842.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".././js/vendors~config-620ba3d9ae4472f968ab.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".././js/config-28c647d3bd0894bac005.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".././js/utilFunctions-1ae3ee4b074ef90d909b.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is how to include for each html file it's own js script which final result should be like this.

**In index.html**

```
// ----- connected scripts in here -------- //
<script type="text/javascript" src=".././js/utilFunctions-1ae3ee4b074ef90d909b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".././js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**In home.html**

```
// ----- connected scripts in here -------- //
<script type="text/javascript" src=".././js/utilFunctions-1ae3ee4b074ef90d909b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".././js/home.js"></script>
</body>
```

I can not add to after `utilFunctions` in `entry` object (inside of `webpack.config.js`) then included part will be in every html  file.

Also I can not add in html files because order should be like this:First plugins  then my own functions.
Please help I stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve like this:

```
entry: {
    language: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts/lang.js'),
    config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts/conf.js'),
    mainFunctions: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts/utilFunctions.js'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts/index.js'),
    home: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts/home.js'),
},
```

Added another two chunks to entry `index` and `home`

And then in **htmlWebpackPlugin** wrote this:

```
['index', 'home'].forEach((file) => {
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: `./html/${file}.html`,
      template: `./src/html/${file}.html`,
      chunks:['language','config','mainFunctions', file],
      minify: {
          removeComments: true,
          // collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          useShortDoctype: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
          keepClosingSlash: true,
      },
    })
  );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control the order where webpack will import your files and import a particular one manually

```
<% if(htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.body) { %>
  <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.body.entry %>"></script>
<% } %>

<script src="home.js"></script>
```

The example you can find also at their repo https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/86f285d5c790a6c15263f5cc50fd666d51f974fd/index.html

Comment: I'm not use `ejs`.I use simple html.

Comment: It does not matter for webpack :)

Comment: If you will take a look on the link in my comment you will see there are using simple html as well

Comment: The problem is the last script `home.js` not generated by the webpack.